# A apoc.import.json procedure with can't read url error

Tags: neo4j

I've installed a neo4j in my lab's centOS server.I want to import a json file into neo4j.
I've already put the apoc-3.3.0.1.jar in the NEO4J_HOME/plugins and add the

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

into neo4j.conf
Then i open the web UI of neo4j with my PC(windows 10) and input the cypher

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///C://Users//stefen//Desktop//test.json")yield value as company
create(c:company)
with c,company
unwind company.organizationInformationList as a
set c = a
```

The json file is saved in my pc. 
And error info is:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url file:/C://Users//stefen//Desktop//test.json as json: /C:/Users/stefen/Desktop/test.json

I have no idea where is the problem.Please help me.
PS:my neo4j version is 3.3.1

Comment: SORRY I've made a huge mistake. I should save the json file in linux server. Now I have solved this problem.

Comment: Hello S. Salva. If you solved your problem, please answer your own question and accept it as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry. I have made a mistake that i forget to put the data file in my server. 
Now i have solved the question.